# Dedicated TMP and AMAVIS

Tags: linux, perl, fstab, amavis

I perfectly configured my server and now I made 2 stupid mistakes, I updated perl along with it's dependencies and I made a dedicated TMP dir and included it in fstab to prevent code execution with a permission of 1777, now amavis shut down and it's not allowing any mail to be sent or received, I activated the webshell for perl as I thought that I broke some perl module and updated 2 modules, which wasn't the fix for my problem and now I need the perl webshell to get back to it's previous state before configuration, I deleted all it's directories but it still prompts the > which means it's configured and I also need to make sure that perl can write to TMP folder so could amavis start creating it's TMPs and get things working again, any ideas ?

Comment: Can you provide relevant parts of /etc/fstab, output of mount, and amavis logs?

Comment: Error in processing, id=25467-01, mime_decode-1 FAILED: MIME::Parser: can't open tmpfile: Invalid argument (in reply to end of DATA command))
(!!)TROUBLE in check_mail: mime_decode-1 FAILED: MIME::Parser: can't open tmpfile: Invalid argument
(!)PRESERVING EVIDENCE in /var/amavis/tmp/amavis-20121226T170616-25469
/var/temp  /tmp    ext3   loop,rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev  0 0

Comment: Can you use http://pastebin.com/ to paste that? Otherwise the formatting is all wonky.

Comment: sorry :) http://pastebin.com/10rVmsb9 and thanks a lot for your time